# Summing data in array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var myData = [
[7106.86000000, 5],
[7107.34000000, 2],
[7107.55000000, 10],
[7107.58000000, 3],
[7107.67000000, 90],
.....
]
```

I need to generate a new array where, on the second element of every row, i need to have the sum of the second element of the previous row, here is the desidered output:

```
var newData = [
[7106.86000000, 5],
[7107.34000000, 7],
[7107.55000000, 17],
[7107.58000000, 20],
[7107.67000000, 110],
.....
]
```

Since 5+2=7, 7+10=17 and so on.

Now i now how to do that with a normal array of elements, where i would have used `reduce`, but i don't know how to handle this with an array of arrays where i need to perform this operation only on the second element of every subarray. What can i use in this case? I was going to use a nested loop but it doesn't look like the most efficient way to do that, since this code will be executed on browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a closure over the sum and map the values while updating the sum with the right part.

```js
var data = [[7106.86000000, 5], [7107.34000000, 2], [7107.55000000, 10], [7107.58000000, 3], [7107.67000000, 90]],
    result = data.map((sum => ([l, r]) => [l, sum += r])(0));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This seems to be the best way to go! Give me 9 minutes to accept your answer!